# Connect multiple VPC to one VPN connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have set up one VPN connection which is connected to a VPC and an on-premise network, now I'm going to have multiple VPC which should have connection to that VPN (the on-premise network). I can not use one VPN per VPC. So I have to connect multiple VPC to one VPN.

As I've searched "Transit VPC" (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-solution-transit-vpc/) is one solution for this case. I'm wondering if this is the best way and if there is any other solution?

Does anyone have experience with "Transit VPC" and can give me some tips?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot because of the on-premise network, they don't like to have /set several vpn connection. So we have to assign our VPCs to one VPN.